# Spring Runtime Error,No identifier specified for entity:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

New to java and spring. Tried creating an app but was unsuccessful.I have the following entity and controller in my app. But at runtime i get an error. I posted snippets for easier reading.

`staff.java`

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Staff {
    private int staff_id;
    private String staff_name;
    private String staff_email;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "staff")
    private List<VisitRequest> visitRequest;


    public String getStaff_name(){
        return staff_name;
    }
    public void setStaff_name(String staff_name){
        this.staff_name = staff_name;
    }
    public String getStaff_email(){
        return staff_email;
    }
    public void setStaff_email(String staff_email){
        this.staff_email = staff_email;
    }

    public int getStaff_id(){
        return staff_id;
    }

    public void setStaff_id(int staff_id){
        this.staff_id = staff_id;
    }


}
```

`StaffController.java`

```
@Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/staff/")
public class StaffController{
@Autowired
    protected StaffRepository staffRepository;


    @GetMapping("/Staff")
    public List<Staff> getAllStaff() {
        return staffRepository.findAll();
    }


    @GetMapping("/staff/{Staff_id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Staff> getStaffById(@PathVariable(value = "Staff_id") Long Staff_id)
    throws ResourceNotFoundException{
    Staff staff = staffRepository.findById(Staff_id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not Found"));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(staff);
```

And the error that is thrown at runtime is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfigura
tion.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.Vportal.data.model.Staff
```

Please advice on what to do.

Comment: possible dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381290/hibernate-exception-org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-specified

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hibernate exception: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com..domain.idea.MAE\_MFEView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381290/hibernate-exception-org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-specified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Staff` entity lacks a member with an `@Id` annotation. This could be added to `staff_id` like follows:

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class Staff {
    @Id
    private int staff_id;

    ....
}
```

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: great but that led to this error. ```nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not
 determine type for: java.util.List, at table: staff, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(visit_request)]
```

Comment: Which means you're one step further. Feel free to open a new question or search for how to properly map `@OneToMany` relationships.