# How to Resolved the error Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: Employee

Tags: java, hibernate

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: Employee
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:86)
    at StoreData.main(StoreData.java:14)

Comment: maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381290/hibernate-exception-org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-specified?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you provide your Employee class. 
What this issue means is your entity class is missing a field, annotated with `@Id`. Every `@Entity` needs and `@Id`, which is the primary key in the database.

Comment: In case we do no create id field in employee table.  then we can not access the employee tables records. if have created in firstname,lastname column in employee table.

Comment: You basically need some kind of id(either '@Id', or '@EmbeddedId' or multiple '@Ids' with an IdClass for composite key). For you ruse case, you can create a composite primary key with both firstname and lastname or to simplify, add a primary key 'id' in the table.

Comment: Ok ,Thank now it is working fine. Am insert and retrieve the records.

Answer (score 0):

`@Entity`
@Table(name = "employee", schema="test")
public class Employee {

```
 @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
private String `firstName`;  


 @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
private String `lastName`;

 public String `getFirstName()` {  
return `firstName`;
```

}
public void `setFirstName(String firstName)`{
    t`his.firstName` = `firstName`;
}

public String `getLastName`() {
    return `lastName`;
}
public void `setLastName`(String `lastName`) {
    `this.lastName` = `lastName`;
}
}