# issue with @oneToMany bi-directional mapping in springboot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to retrieve data from 2 tables in MySql using spring boot and hibernate @OneToMany bi-directional mapping. But am getting this error among others:
No identifier specified for entity: com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.Action

Please Check the error trace below:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-14 18:56:59.251 ERROR 8200 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.Action
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at com.dafe.spring.applogger.AppLoggerApplication.main(AppLoggerApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.Action
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1215) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1246) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1830) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

the class the error is pointing to is below but I don't seem to know what the problem is. Find below is the com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.Action class :

```
package com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Entity
@Table(name="action")
public class Action {

    //declare & annotate your fields
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
    private int id;

@Column(name="time")
    private Timestamp logTime;

@Column(name="type")
    private String logType;

@Column(name="log_id")
    private int userLogId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="log_id")
private UserLog userLog;

public Action(int id, Timestamp logTime, String logType, int userLogId, UserLog userLog) {
    this.id = id;
    this.logTime = logTime;
    this.logType = logType;
    this.userLogId = userLogId;
    this.userLog = userLog;
}

    //create and generate constructor
    public Action() {

    }

    public Action(Timestamp logTime, String logType, int userLogId) {
        this.logTime = logTime;
        this.logType = logType;
        this.userLogId = userLogId;
    }


    //generate getters and setters

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getLogTime() {
        return logTime;
    }

    public void setLogTime(Timestamp logTime) {
        this.logTime = logTime;
    }

    public String getLogType() {
        return logType;
    }

    public void setLogType(String logType) {
        this.logType = logType;
    }

    public int getLogId() {
        return userLogId;
    }

    public void setLogId(int logId) {
        this.userLogId = logId;
    }


    public UserLog userLog() {
        return userLog;
    }

    public void setLogs(UserLog userLog) {
        this.userLog = userLog;
    }

    //generate toString 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Action [id=" + id + ", logTime=" + logTime + ", logType=" + logType + ", userLogId=" + userLogId + "]";
    }


}
```

The action class is supposed to fetch data from database and has a foreign key relationship with class UserLog.

```
package com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="log")
public class UserLog {

    //define field

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name="session_id")
    private String sessionId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="log",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private ArrayList<Action>action;
    //define constructors

    public UserLog(String userId, String sessionId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }
    //define getters and setters


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }


    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    public String getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }


    public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }

    public ArrayList<Action> getAction() {
        return action;
    }


    public void setAction(ArrayList<Action> action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    //convenience method for Action
    public void addAction(Action tempAction) {

        if (action == null) {
        action = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        action.add(tempAction);
    }


    //define toString

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Log [id=" + id + ", userId=" + userId + ", sessionId=" + sessionId + "]";
    }



}
```

please help me figure out the problem and a possible solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported the Id from the wrong package.This error can be thrown when you import a different library for `@Id` than `javax.persistance.Id ;`

So change

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
```

To

```
import javax.persistence.Id
```

Refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381290/hibernate-throws-org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-specified-for/4381360#4381360)

Comment: thanks, after correcting it, another error shows up: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @ OneToMany, @ ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.UserLog.action

Comment: As a requirement persistent collection-valued fields must be declared as an interface type so please change ArrayList to List like this. private List<Action>action;

Answer (score 0):

I think an issue is related to this mapping:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy="log",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private ArrayList<Action>action;
```

`mappedBy` points to the name of the property on the 'owning' side. So in your case you should specify `mappedBy="userLog"` as it's defined in Action class

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="log_id")
private UserLog userLog;
```

Comment: thanks for your response but the error still persists after making that correction

Comment: thanks, after correcting it, another error shows up: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @ OneToMany, @ ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.UserLog.action