# Crashing at start when using jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

So, I'm trying to implement a database into a kafka listener, but when i start it, it crashed and i can't figure out why.

here's the code

Model

```java
package br.com.ottimizza.ListenerServico.domain.model;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "ot_log_questor_post_baixa")
public class LogQuestor {
  
  @Id
  @Column
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private BigInteger id;

  @Column
  Date ot_created_at;
  
  @Column
  Body ot_objeto_questor;
  
  @Column
  String ot_objeto_texto_questor;

  @Column
  String ot_status_req;

  @Column
  String ot_token_usuario;

}
```

Body Object

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Body implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  
  String fileLink;

  String zenTokenUsuario;

  String domain;

  String filename;

  String cnpj;

  HashMap<String, String> propriedades;

}
```

Repository

```java
package br.com.ottimizza.ListenerServico.repository;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.com.ottimizza.ListenerServico.domain.model.LogQuestor;

@Repository
public interface LogQuestorRepository extends JpaRepository<LogQuestor, BigInteger> {
  
  public Optional<LogQuestor> findById(BigInteger id);
}
```

the method to save it

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

  @Autowired
  LogQuestorRepository repository;

  public void saveToDB(String message, String status, String token) {
    LogQuestor reqToSv = new LogQuestor();
    //assignment of carachteristics
    repository.save(reqToSv);
  }
```

Note: the code has some things that were ommited but nothing that's wrong or relevant, I'm sure

The error i'm getting

```
2022-10-21T20:32:34.903633+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-10-21 20:32:34.903  WARN 4 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logQuestorRepository' defined in br.com.ottimizza.ListenerServico.repository.LogQuestorRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: br.com.ottimizza.ListenerServico.domain.model.LogQuestor
2022-10-21T20:32:34.904798+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-10-21 20:32:34.904  WARN 4 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'services': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tareffa'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'br.com.ottimizza.ListenerServico.client.ClientTareffa': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logQuestorRepository' defined in br.com.ottimizza.ListenerServico.repository.LogQuestorRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: br.com.ottimizza.ListenerServico.domain.model.LogQuestor
2022-10-21T20:32:34.905820+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-10-21 20:32:34.904  INFO 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4381290/18157 - Please read the top several answers ... there are multiple problems possible here, including using the wrong `@Id` annotation class.

Comment: @JimGarrison you were correct, it was the wrong id class, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the wrong `@Id` annotation class import.

I was importing the
`import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;`

and the correct was
`import javax.persistence.Id;`

Thanks a lot [@JimGarrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18157/jim-garrison)